# How to show alert on firebase auth errors flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to show an alert dialog when there is an error in the firebase auth.
Firebase already prints the error in the UI but i want to show a dialog to the user.

Heres my createUser and signInUser Funtion and my signup button function

```
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword({String email,password,username,image,phoneNumber}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

```
 Future signInWithEmailAndPassword({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password
      );
      User user = userCredential.user;
      assert(user.uid != null);
      email = user.email;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
    }
  }
```

```
            press: () {
              if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                formKey.currentState.save();
                    context
                    .read<Authentication>()
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: emailController.text,
                    password: passwordController.text)
                    .whenComplete(() => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            HomeScreen())));
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an `AlertDialog` widget similar to this.  The Yes/No buttons are probably overkill in your situation and if so, just convert to an `ok` button and then you don't have to check the return result.

```
Future<String> showYesNoAlertDialog({
  @required BuildContext context,
  @required String titleText,
  @required String messageText,
}) async {
  // set up the buttons
  final Widget yesButton = FlatButton(
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'yes'),
    child: const Text('Yes'),
  );
  final Widget noButton = FlatButton(
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'no'),
    child: const Text('No'),
  );

  // set up the AlertDialog
  final alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text(titleText),
    content: Text(messageText),
    actions: [
      yesButton,
      noButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => alert,
  );
}
```

Then where you have your print statements outputting the errors, you'd call the above widget like this

```
final dr = await showYesNoAlertDialog(
  context: context,
  titleText: 'Authentication Error',
  messageText:
      'There has been an error during authentication.  Would you like to retry?',
);

if (dr == 'yes') {
  // Yes button clicked
}
else {
  // No button clicked
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i have another question "my app navigates to the next screen even when there is error in the firebase auth" how can i stop that?

Comment: @PetersVictor ```whenComplete()``` method defines ```The [action] function is called when this future completes, whether it does so with a value or with an error.``` so even its succesful or error login this will always be called .For  your situation after the your method signInWithEmailAndPassword() is complete it will always navigate based on your code

Comment: Thank you Reign, so how will i make sure the login or signup is successful before moving to the next page